# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED CORS

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

I am working on a sample Angular & ASP.Net Core project. The Project is available at

https://github.com/TryCatchLearn/DatingApp.git

I am getting error in console of Google Chrome when I do ng serve as below

`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

It seems we need to add code to apply CORS in the Application.

I have made changes in the App as below

```
app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowCredentials()
        .WithOrigins("https://localhost:4200"));
```

But the error message shows as

```
`Http failure response for https://localhost:5001/api/account/login: 0 Unknown Error`
```

**I have tried like below but still the same error is coming..**

```
app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowCredentials()
                .WithOrigins("https://localhost:4200", "https://localhost:5001"));
```

Where I need to do the change.

Comment: You have diffrent port in origins and error message. Try to change that port to 5001 its looks like app is running on that.

Comment: Even after changing to new 5001 URL, I am getting the same error.

Comment: Edited Question for more clarity.

Comment: It seems it is a preflight CORS error. How to handle that error.